# Why i get this error in my haskell code

Tags: haskell

Why i get this error in my code:
code:

```
module Task5 where

import Prelude

data Stream a = a :& Stream a

infixl 4 :&

add :: Num a => a -> a -> a
add a b = a + b

instance Num (Stream a ) where
    (+) (ia:&a) (ib :& b) = (ia + ib) :& ((+) a b)
```

error:

```
Task5.hs:14:33:
    No instance for (Num a) arising from a use of `+'
    Possible fix:
      add (Num a) to the context of the instance declaration
    In the first argument of `(:&)', namely `(ia + ib)'
    In the expression: (ia + ib) :& ((+) a b)
    In an equation for `+':
        + (ia :& a) (ib :& b) = (ia + ib) :& ((+) a b)
```

I don't understand how to correct this , i tried it for all week , but not find any solution. So , can you say me what i  should correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error suggests, you need to add `Num a` to the "context" of your instance declaration:

```
instance Num a => Num (Stream a) where
```

Otherwise the `ia + ib` operation doesn't have any `(+)` operation available, as that is acting on the individual stream members.